# Handle appear.in applications as api calls

Tags: javascript, python, api

Is there any way to access the appear.in API ([Developer page](https://developer.appear.in/)) via python? I want to create a user with the API and with that credentials, I then want to create multiple rooms.  I am assigning each rooms to separate  persons hence I am storing the details in a database.  Any help?

Comment: I cleaned up spelling/grammar and added a link the the appear.in developer page.  Poster still needs to provide some examples of what they tried, and the answer from looking at the page I linked appears to be a simple, no, they do not provide that level of API access

Comment: @Foon thank you..for your comments

Answer (score 2):

Developer at appear.in here. The short answer is no, we don't support that kind of functionality. We aim to be a very low-end API solution for those that need video and just that. If you need more advanced support, I recommend checking out http://simplewebrtc.com/. They offer more advanced features, but requires a bit more work.

Feel free to contact us at api@appear.in as well with your questions, that will get you answers much quicker :)